# min-height does not work in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I'm trying to set the min height of an element but its not working in IE. Can someone please help? I googled and the fix for this doesn't work either. The fix is below (this doesn't work).

```
min-height: 130px;
height auto !important;
height: 130px;
```

Here's my css:

```
.example {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 80px;
    transition: transform 0.3s;
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.26, 0.89);
    will-change: transform;
    text-align: left;
    min-height: 390px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    flex-flow: nowrap;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Works for me https://jsfiddle.net/j9Lb3875/ What version of IE?

Comment: Does my fiddle do what you expected?  If not, what do you want to happen instead?

Comment: that works. not sure why its not working for me. Maybe its because I'm using flex?

Comment: checkout this snippet http://codepen.io/chriswrightdesign/pen/emQNGZ

Answer (score 0):

I added a `border:1px solid red;` to visualize the table.  It seems to work fine for me in IE11.  Check to see that your div is not being constrained by its surroundings.  If it doesn't have room to expand it wont.

Use F12 to open the developer panel in IE.  From there you can inspect elements and find out what CSS rules are being applied.  If you still have trouble, add borders to everything in the area so you know exactly which div is taking up which space, and whether the space is padding, margin, or otherwise.

https://jsfiddle.net/j9Lb3875/1/